# Fluent Web.Config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, fluent-interface

Has anyone made an attempt at something like similar to the [Fluent-Nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fluent-nhibernate) project except for web.config? Is this even plausible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. In Microsoft's [**Enterprise Library 5**](http://entlib.codeplex.com/) a **fluent configuration API** has been added to configure your application at runtime without using a configuration file such as `web.config` or `app.config`.

See these articles for examples:

- [CodeProject: Enterprise Library 5 Fluent Configuration API](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Fluent_Configuration_API.aspx)
- [Bart Wullems: Enterprise Library 5 Fluent](http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2010/11/enterprise-library-5-fluent.html)